# Existence of polynomial

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Let $f(x) $ denotes a polynomial in one variable with real coefficients, such that $f(a) =1$ for some real number $a$ . Does there exist a polynomial $ g(x) $ with real coefficients such that, if $p(x) =f(x) g(x) $, then $p(a) =1, p'(a) =0=p''(a)$? Justify your answer.

My try:By the hypothesis, $g(a) =1$, $p'(a) =0$ implies $f'(a) +g'(a) =0$ and $p''(a) =0$ implies $f''(a)+2f'(a)g'(a)+g''(a)=0$.
So we get three equations. If we consider $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that degree of $p(x)>4$ then we get unknown(coefficients) greater than 3. Hence we get infinitely many polynomials. Please help to solve the question. Thanks in advance

Comment: So you know how to calculate $C_0=g(a)$, $C_1=g'(a)$ and $C_2=g''(a)$. Are you familiar with Taylor polynomials?

Comment: Do you mean Taylor series?

Comment: hint : You want to prove the existence of a polynomial $g$ such that $f(x)g(x)-1$ is divisible by $(x-a)^2$, ie such that there exists a polynomial $t(x)$ such that $f(x)g(x)=1+(x-a)^2t(x)$. Note that $f(x)$ and $(x-a)^2$ are relatively prime in $\mathbb{R}[x]$

Comment: A Taylor polynomial is what you get when you truncate a Taylor series after a certain number of terms, chopping off all the high degre terms and leave only terms of degree $\le k$.

Comment: Ok. But here I dont know from where I can chop off

Comment: Your calculation show that to meet the requirements all you need is that $g(a)$, $g'(a)$ and $g''(a)$ have the prescribed values. This suggests to me that a quadratic polynomial $g(x)$ will do, don't you think?

Comment: I cannot understand how to say that p(x) is quadratic polynomial

Comment: The Taylor expansion of $g(x)$ is what I'm interested in. I think a quadratic $g(x)$ will do. We were not given the degree of $f(x)$, so there is no way to predict the degree of $p(x)$. The factor $g(x)$ is what you can adjust and have full control over.

Comment: Viewed differently: If $p(x)$ works so does $p(x)+f(x)(x-a)^3r(x)$ because the latter term vanishes at $a$ as do its first and second derivatives.